# Как сделать оповещение в чате (узнать о приходе новых сообщений)?

Tags: javascript, php

Как сделать оповещение в чате (узнать о приходе новых сообщений)?

Есть ли способ не делать каждые х-секунд запросы на сервер, появились ли новые сообщения? В общем, нужно сделать чат и обновить список сообщений.

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое HTML5 WebSocket, Long/short Polling, AJAX, WebRTC, Server-Sent Events?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536784/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events)

Answer (score 6):

- http://learn.javascript.ru/websockets
- http://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events
- http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet/long-poll

---

- http://socket.io/
- http://faye.jcoglan.com/
- https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client
- http://ape-project.org/
- https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor
- и т.п. и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Вам помогут "Comet Server" или "websocket".

Answer (score -6):

Поиграйте с

```
    // новое сообщение //
    function playTitle()
        {
        document.title = "__ Новое сообщение __";
        window.setTimeout('document.title="|| Новое сообщение ||";', 1000);
        window.setTimeout('document.title="__ Новое сообщение __";', 2000);
        window.setTimeout('document.title="|| Новое сообщение ||";', 3000);

        if (playTitleFlag == true)
            {
            window.setTimeout('playTitle();', 4000);
            }
        }
```

А вообще уточняйте, что конкретно вы хотите сделать, что пробовали, что не получилось.

Comment: > Есть ли способ не делать какждые х-секунд запросы на сервер

Теперь ясно, откуда такая дикая уважуха))

Comment: Лопни мои глаза, и это 2015 год.

Comment: нормально так. хочешь человеку помочь, а тебя минусуют. неблагодарные

Comment: Не минусуют, а оценивают ответ, а он:
1. Не в кассу;
2. Это очень плохой код.

Comment: пожалуйста. напишите лучше. я на своём проекте использую именно этот код. проблем никаких не испытываю.