# Динамическое обновление контента

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Давным-давно видел вопрос о том, как обновлять контент, который выводится из базы данных через javascript, не используя таймеры. Ну, например, как **vk**, когда приходят оповещения о новых сообщениях. Они ведь не могут ставить таймер, чтоб обновлять контент каждую секунду, тогда **вопрос:** как они творят такую магию вне Хогвартса? Что это за библиотеки и вообще как называется такой метод получения данных из базы данных?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Всё сложно) Подробнее можно прочитать тут:
[Ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/company/vkontakte/blog/214877/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут похожая проблема: [Как сделать оповещение в чате (узнать о приходе новых сообщений)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/396019/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "они не могут"?) Посмотрите консоль, для отслеживания онлайн состояния пользователя, как раз по таймеру дергается сервер