# Как сделать чат и моментальную отслежку изменения какого-либо значения?

Tags: php, сокет, chat

Добрый день.

Как сделать отслежку определённого значения? Например, я устанавливаю значение `Пользователи_Онлайн или Количество_Товара_На_Складе`. Другие пользователи изменяют эти значения, и они тут же видны всем.

Без SetInterval-ов и периодических подключения, чтоб не грузить сервер. Как ни странно, конкретный пример нашёл только один - работает http://habrahabr.ru/post/41223/ . Вроде и код не сложный, но разобрать сам механизм не могу, чтоб добавлять свои данные. 
И, по-моему, конкретно в нём "связь" с сокетом лишь только в названии (сокет чат).
Стоит ли использовать сокеты, если да, то как именно это всё делать?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, посмотрите в сторону [WebSocket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Все знакомые мне инструменты я перечисли [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/392060/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-comet-long-polling#392092)

Answer (score 1):

Тот же принцип то указан [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/396019#396024).

Comment: @VasyOk Там указана в основном информация про Comet-костыль и серверные реализации на других языках. Не слово про [Ratchet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet), [ReactPHP](https://github.com/reactphp/react) и [PHPDaemon](https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon)

Кроме того, тот вопрос им же и задан.

Comment: Да, вы правы, моя невнимательность. :(

Comment: А можно Ratchet установить на стандартный хостинг? Он полностью на php или там есть dll-ки?

Comment: К сожалению, требует [libevent](http://goo.gl/Y7hpuF), как, впрочем, и [PHPDaemon](http://goo.gl/Dnx3Di). Последний ещё кучу всего. Да и long polling (не WebSocket) демон [dklab_realplexor](http://goo.gl/iwFp1K) написанный на perl-е ([есть и вариант на плюсах](http://goo.gl/8nOUD6)) требует запуска, как сервис, т.е. без root-а никак.


["Это вам не это"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef_dGigQK9Q). Любое подобное решение, что-нибудь да и потребует, к примеру, php-расширение [shmop](http://goo.gl/hcipCo). Тот же libevent для взаимодействия с php треубет [pecl-event](http://goo.gl/gHfD8e).