# Обновление информации на странице

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте заинтересовал вопрос. Например как у вк или gmail или того же icq. Просто в консоли, запросы к серверу(вк), уходят с периодичностью примерно 15 секунд, но сообщение как и полагается приходят сразу после отправки их собеседником.Когда сообщение приходит страница обращается к серверу даже в середине 15ти секундного интервала. С помощью чего можно подобное реализовать или по какому принципу работает обновление входящих сообщений или как хотя бы это называется?
Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Можно конечно с секундным интервалом стучатся на сервер, но мне кажется это как по колхозному что ли.

Comment: Поищите информацию про веб-сокеты.

Comment: Запросы каждую секунду - просто polling, каждые 15 секунд - long polling. Но вебсокеты лучше их обоих, да

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое HTML5 WebSocket, Long/short Polling, AJAX, WebRTC, Server-Sent Events?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536784/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это новая технология последние несколько лет используется. Называется Websocket.

Сначала были только бинарные клиенты tcp/ip, udp и обычный http. Но обычного http не хватало для полноценной работы. Принцип http передать всю информацию и закрыть соединение - очень неудобно.

И Adobe первая выпустила Flash плеер, технология, которая позволяет в html страничку встраивать бинарный код по сути и использовать тот же tcp.

Потом http развивался с js, и сейчас дошли до того, что Adobe прижали (все крупные компании сказали, мы не пустим Adobe на рынок), якобы устаревшая технология. ИМХО, я лично не согласен с этим, почему нам диктуют чем пользоваться = заставляют. Я за свободную конкуренцию.

И сейчас появился мутированный html5+js, который позволяет внутри html встраивать так называемые вебсокеты. Это такая штука которая постоянно держит соединение с сервером. Как тот же самый бинарный клиент.

Вообщем грубо говоря хотели уйти от бинарных клиентов, а пришли к ним же. Только в веб версии. :)

PS Кстати несмотря на то что Flash просто можно сказать задавили. Она всё равно живёт. И не удивлюсь если будет жить дальше, гиков у Flash очень много и кумиров.

Comment: "*Adobe прижали (все крупные компании сказали, мы не пустим Adobe на рынок), якобы устаревшая технология.*" - что я сейчас прочитал

Comment: @Etki российское мифотворчество во всей красе

Comment: Тогда как было по вашему? :) Что же флэш на IOs не работает и на андройд? :) Случайность? Забыли добавить?