# Как сделать автообновления чата ajax без тысячи запросов

Tags: php

Вообщем сделал я чат PHP + AJAX + MYSQL все работает отлично, но меня смущает одно дело... чтобы интерактивно не обновляя страницы проверить есть ли новое сообщение нужно отправить AJAX запрос, чтобы все было быстро я отправляю этот запрос с проверкой каждую секунду и вот что собственно меня смущает... В минуту отправляется 60 запросов, смотрел на других сайтах с чатом, там такого нет, и вот вопрос: я зря беспокоюсь? и как можно сделать альтернативно автообновление

Comment: нужно использовать сокеты :)

Comment: Я так и думал! Но вот вопрос! для сокетов надо чтобы на серверной стороне всегда работал скрипт PHP, и если сделаю на сокетах будет лучше? или разницы нет?

Comment: Нет, сокеты на php  Вы нормальные не сделаете, их нужно разворачивать на js (socket.io) например. Да, сокеты будут идеальным вариантом.

Comment: go  to http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536784/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Длинные опросы** – отличная альтернатива частым опросам. Они также удобны в реализации, и при этом сообщения доставляются без задержек.

**Схема:**

1) Отправляется запрос на сервер.

2) Соединение не закрывается сервером, пока не появится сообщение.

3) Когда сообщение появилось – сервер отвечает на запрос, пересылая данные.

4) Браузер тут же делает новый запрос.
Ситуация, когда браузер отправил запрос и держит соединение с сервером, ожидая ответа, является стандартной и прерывается только доставкой сообщений.

**Схема коммуникации:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если соединение рвётся само, например, из-за ошибки в сети, то браузер тут же отсылает новый запрос.

Примерный код клиентской части:

```
function subscribe(url) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState != 4) return;

if (this.status == 200) {
  onMessage(this.responseText);
} else {
  onError(this);
}

subscribe(url);
}
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
}
```

Функция subscribe делает запрос, при ответе обрабатывает результат, и тут же запускает процесс по новой.

Сервер, конечно же, должен уметь работать с большим количеством таких «ожидающих» соединений.

[источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-longpoll)

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, лучшим решением с точки зрения оптимизации нагрузки является постоянное соединение с сервером через [WebSocket](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets). При этом сервер сам рассылает обновления одновременно всем подключенным клиентам, а не каждый клиент спрашивает у сервера не произошло ли каких-то обновлений.

Но сокеты требуют значительного изменения серверной архитектуры, а это не всегда возможно. В таком случае можно использовать [длинные опросы](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-longpoll#%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B):

1. Отправляется запрос на сервер.
2. Соединение не закрывается сервером, пока не появится сообщение.
3. Когда сообщение появилось – сервер отвечает на запрос, пересылая данные.
4. Браузер тут же делает новый запрос.

Это позволяет снизить нагрузку на сервер и ускорить появение свежих данных на клиенте путём небольших изменений на сервере.