# Взаимодействие между пользователями с помощью jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

Возможно ли средствами `Jquery ajax` реализовать взаимодействие между пользователями?

На сайте авторизовались два пользователя, один с них вносит изменение в бд, доступ к которой имеют одновременно (например: содержимое которой открыто в обоих - они одновременно видят одинаковые данные) , нужно что б и второй пользователь после сохранений этих даных, без перезагрузки страницы - увидел их!

**Возможно ли это сделать на Jquery ajax ? Или нужна какая то другая технология ?**

Comment: meteor это могет из коробки

Comment: Вы об этом? [Что-такое-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536784/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events)

Comment: Сделать на ajax возможно, но, как кто-то сказал в какой-то теме: в 2016 году уже пора переходить на вебсокеты

Answer (score 1):

Ну в общем то для этого и нужен ajax. Если нужно поставьте

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({тело запроса})
}, 1000) - здесь интервал обновления данных
```

Ну и выводите новый результат в в какой-то элемент на странице. Так что в связке php+jquery такие пишутся вообще на лету

Comment: А возможно что б не обновлять вчерез промежуток времени, а только тогда - когда в бд поступает новая запись? И не будит ли проблем когда в один и тот же момент в несколько пользователей захотят внести изменения?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, вроде jquery такое не провернешь, потому что мы не можем без запроса на сервера узнать об изменениях на сервере. Так что в запросе можно прописать какой-то идентификатор запроса, и смотреть если он последний то информацию не обновлять, но вообще если несколько пользователей будут вносить изменения одновременно, то просто сохранится последнее

Comment: наверное все таки нужно будет в ускоренном режиме изучать node.js и socket.io

Comment: И дергать базу раз в секунду? А если пользователей тысяча..... у вас сервер не умрет?