# Отлавливать изменения в блоке и оповещать об этом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите какими современными методами можно отловить изменения внутри блока?
Допустим внутри блока `.messages` сейчас такое дерево:

```
<div id="you">
<div id="author">%AUTHOR%</div>
<div id="text">%MESSAGE%</div>
</div>
<div id="talker">
<div id="author">%AUTHOR%</div>
<div id="text">%MESSAGE%</div>
</div>
```

После отправки AJAX запроса, полученный от него ответ заносится в блок и теперь там такое дерево:

```
<div id="you">
<div id="author">%AUTHOR%</div>
<div id="text">%MESSAGE%</div>
</div>
<div id="talker">
<div id="author">%AUTHOR%</div>
<div id="text">%MESSAGE%</div>
</div>

<div id="you">
<div id="author">%AUTHOR%</div>
<div id="text">%MESSAGE%</div>
</div>
<div id="talker">
<div id="author">%AUTHOR%</div>
<div id="text">%MESSAGE%</div>
</div>
```

Мне необходимо что-бы к моменту "увеличения" блока пользователю выводилось оповещение о поступлении новых сообщений. Как это сделать?

Comment: Причем тут чат  и какое-то непонятное `предыдущее содержимое меньше настоящего - выводить alert.` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое HTML5 WebSocket, Long/short Polling, AJAX, WebRTC, Server-Sent Events?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536784/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events)

Comment: Объясняю проще - как вывести оповещение при обнаружении новых сообщений?

Comment: ну например [25 Best jQuery Notification plugins](http://jqueryhouse.com/best-jquery-notification-plugins/)

Comment: Упростил до нельзя вопрос. Надеюсь теперь поймете.

Comment: jQuery плагинами не пользуюсь, позже вообще планирую переписать все на чистый JS.

Comment: Может, вместо "пришло новое сообщение -> добавить его в список" и "проверять высоту списка, при изменении выдать пользователю алерт" сделать "пришло новое сообщение -> выдать пользователю алирт и добавить сообщение в список"?

Answer (score 0):

тут нужно больше конкретики, так как для решения данного вопроса множество решений:

1. Если это нужно указывать только пользователю, который отправляет сообщение, то после отправки ajax запроса приходит ответ и исходя из этого ответа можно показывать уведомление если сообщение добавлено и не нужно считать кол-во и высоту блоков.
2. Если это чекается автоматом, лучше использовать аля сокетные штуки, но на край можно повесить проверку о наличии новых сообщений через setInterval, внутри него повесить ajax запрос на получении информации о новых сообщений или о кол-ве всех сообщений данного юзера и сравнивать с значением текущим