# Существуют ли у AJAX аналоги

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Опытные web-программисты, расскажите, пожалуйста, насколько актуален AJAX в 2017 и есть ли какая-нибудь альтернатива данной технологии. Сам я чайник, так что прошу не сетовать. Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: смотря в каком направлении альтернатива...... можно обновлять контент страницы без перезагрузки, а может тебя интересует  например чат....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  пожалуй меня интерисуют два варианта

Comment: чаты не делаются на технологии AJAX'a, там совершенно другой подход. AJAX вполне актуален и часто юзается, но посмотрите еще в сторону WebSocket

Comment: Выбор невелик. Только WebSocket

Comment: @Manitikyl т.е если я захочу реализовать что то вроде чата, с помощью которого можно общаться с консультантом, то лучше юзать WebSocket

Comment: да, на websocket будет куда удачнее чем на ajax

Comment: а что Вы сами нашли для решения своей задачи? что нашли в гугле по своему вопросу ? *Сам я чайник ...* - это не оправдание.

Comment: @Alex читаю кингу ajax и php разработка динамических веб-приложений книжка 2007 года. После прочтения нескольких глав посетила мысль, а  вообще актуален ли на данный момент AJAX и что  используют опытные программисты на сегодняшний день.

Comment: Для управления контентом на странице, записями - AJAX. А если чаты, или приложения которые требуют постоянного обновления - то только вебсокет.

Comment: вы бы книжку поновее нашли лучше, нечего археологией заниматься

Comment: также может быть полезен вопрос: [Что такое HTML5 WebSocket, Long/short Polling, AJAX, WebRTC, Server-Sent Events?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536784/227016)

Comment: @teran может у вас на примете есть какие-нибудь книги по новее?

Comment: на примете нет, но вы возьмите хотя бы что нить за последние 5 лет, не старше. а то вы читаете когда в ходу еще пхп 4 был, аякс только повляться стал, jquery еще и не вышел, с БД работали через `mysql_*`, который счас вообще не используется, а понятия адаптивной верстки вообще отсутствовало, основными бразуерами были ИЕ7 и фф3, небось, а хром еще только в задумках авторов был. Принципы конечно остались, главное при чтении понимать, что технологии шагнули вперед.

Comment: @teran хорошо, спасибо за совет

Comment: @Vadim на Ваш вопрос есть ответы в гугле. Рекомендую читать книги не старше 2-3 лет (если не интересуетесь историей) и активно пользоваться поисковиком. Кроме этого, если Вы делаете чат, то об этом стоит написать в вопросе, так сможете получить более качественный ответ. В текущем виде это скорее вопрос-оффтопик .

Comment: @Vadim [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458485/191482) - выбери поновее, например PHP 7. Дмитрий Котеров, Игорь Симдянов. явно новая книга......... и [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/191482) - чтобы не было вопросов о том, в ходу ли еще технологии.......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Прямого аналога **Ajax** как отдельной технологии пока что не существует.

Но, важно понимать, что то, что раньше делалось *исключительно* с помощью **Ajax** - сейчас можно сделать с использованием других технологий.

Например, раньше типичный чат или динамически обновляемый контент (первые всплывающие сообщения в вк работали с использованием ajax) на странице делался только с помощью **Ajax** (по кулдауну дергался сервер, что создавало неимоверную нагрузку), сейчас это намного быстрее (как в плане скорости разработки так и в плане быстродействия написанного), качественнее и проще сделать с помощью **WebSocket**. Советую Вам почитать о веб-сокетах, а раз Вы пишите на PHP попробуйте [Ratchet.](http://socketo.me/)

Понимание работы и представление о том, что можно сделать с помощью websocket'ов значительно поможет Вам не использовать ajax, где это можно легче сделать на сокетах.

Comment: что-то ответ получился только о чате с сокетами)) а в целом где ajax применяется как самомстоятельная единица не написано и почему. было бы неплохо увидеть чуть более широко, например без ajax точно никуда при таком сяком и третьим пунктах....а заменить можно тут там и здесь к примеру