# Как организовать общение между сервером и клиентом в реальном времени

Tags: android, firebase, клиент-сервер, fcm

Изучаю самостоятельно Android и столкнулся с тем, что не знаю как правильно организовать общение между клиентом и сервером.

Например, есть сервер(php) и есть *клиент-1* и *клиент-2*. *Клиент-1* посылает на сервер запрос на добавление *клиента-2* "в друзья".

Как правильно сделать так, чтобы *клиент-2* получил или хоть как-то отработал данный запрос в реальном времени?

И так же чтобы после того как клиент-2 ответит "согласием", клиент-1 также получил бы об этом уведомление сразу?

Хотелось бы услышать различные варианты, я же наверно буду прав предположив что отсылать запрос на проверку сервера каждые n секунд не совсем верное решение? =)

Плюс недавно услышал про Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), но пока не до конца понял поможет ли он мне с этим.

Буду рад любым Вашим пинкам в нужном направлении! =)

Comment: я так понимаю, вас интересует сама концепция? Т.е. вы еще не писали ни сервер, ни клиенты?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое HTML5 WebSocket, Long/short Polling, AJAX, WebRTC, Server-Sent Events?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536784/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events)

Comment: возможно не совсем дубликат из-за [tag:android], но вполне себе варианты

Comment: Я писал серверы и клиенты но примитивные, по типу что только клиенты отправляют запросы серверу сами, но я так понимаю в различных месенджерах и соц.сетях общение идёт в обе стороны? Сервер ведь должен как то уведомить клиент что данные обновились или есть новые

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сырые WebSockets использовать не рекомендую.

Самое лучшее решение - Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

1. В приложение определяете обработчик пушей.
2. С [сервера отправляете пуши](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) с помощью библиотеки вроде [этой](https://github.com/Paragraph1/php-fcm).
3. Когда клиент получает пуш о том, что его добавляют в друзья, что-нибудь делаете. К примеру, сразу открываете `Activity`. После принятия/отклонения запроса на дружбу либо с помощью того же FCM посылаете сообщение, либо отправляете https запрос на ваш php сервер, а он отошлёт пуш тому, кто изначально отправил запрос на дружбу.

Comment: открою небольшой секрет: FCM - это обертка над websockets :)

Comment: @Grundy обёртка, которую писала куча специалистов, которая явно лучше, чем сырые вебсокеты. Но ответ подправил, совсем не то написал, что хотел O:

Answer (score 3):

Обычно, для общения в клиента и сервера в реальном времени, а также для отправки PUSH сообщений сервером клиену( т.е. клиен не отправляет запрос, сервер сам отправляет ему какую-то информация) используется протокол WebSockets.

Реализации данного протокола существуют как в Java так и в PHP. 
Вам нужно будет написать сервер(как я понял на PHP) который будет работать по протоколу WebSockets и обсуживать клиентов(мобильные приложения).

Вот это может быть вам полезно https://stfalcon.com/ru/blog/post/android-websocket

Comment: Спасибо за нужное направление, про WebSocket обязательно почитаю.