# Настройка xhr запросов на получение данных

Tags: javascript, ajax, веб-программирование, xhr

Недавно начал изучать xhr запросы. В процессе внедрения технологии в проект возникла необходимость в отображении изменений файлов в директории сервера. Решил пока что реализовать отправку запроса на сервер каждые 2 секунды. Насколько корректно такое решение? И есть ли альтернативный вариант?

Comment: Вебсокеты. . . .

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536785/191482